# How to clean binary image using horizontal projection?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to remove anything other than text from a license plate with a binary filter.

I have the projections on each axis but I don't know how to apply it. My idea is to erase the white outlines.

This is the image I'm working for now:

[image]

This is the projection in Axis X:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pylab

(rows,cols)=img.shape
h_projection = np.array([ x/255/rows for x in img.sum(axis=0)])
plt.plot(range(cols), h_projection.T)
```

And this is the result:

[image]

As you can see in the graph, at the end the line is shot by the white contour.

How can I erase everything that is at a certain threshold of the photo? Every help is appreciated

Comment: did you check [thresholding operator from OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html)? I think that's the erase everything at a certain threshold that you asked for. Otherwise I can suggest checking [morphological operators in OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) if you need to shrink the white part to obtain a cleaner image.

Comment: Thanks, if I have checked the documentation, in fact the binary image uses a series of filters, including threshold. The problem is when the program captures the license plate, it leaves contours, so when I want to segment characters, it makes the results difficult. According to the documentation, using vertical and horizontal histograms is a good way to remove edges, as part of the segmentation stage.

Comment: ok. Maybe you can use the threshold again on the histograms? I am not sure about what exactly you are trying to achieve, do you have an example? I am not sure what outlines, contours and edges exactly means (from what I understood, the erosion morphological operator should help, but maybe I got it wrong). Or can you point out the documentation for horizontal and vertical histogram?

Comment: I want to segment characters to read them with a CNN, I'm at this part https://miro.medium.com/max/704/1*P4GoiHrMfvGcf-lGkXMstQ.png

Comment: yeah, but why not thresholding again? Just in one dimension, this time.
If you have your array as numpy array, `np.where(data < 0.25)` will give you an array of with `True` for all values below 0.25 and `False` for the rest. Then you have found the black parts between the letters as in the image, the one highlighted in green. 
If you want more sophisticated, you can look for local minima in your function (where the black parts are) with [`scipy.signal.findpeaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html), just use `1-your_signal` as input.

Comment: Could you give a small example to understand it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to extract the black areas within the white characters.
For example, you can select the columns (or rows) in your histograms where the value is less than a certain threshold.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pylab
import numpy as np


img = plt.imread('binary_image/iXWgw.png')
(rows,cols)=img.shape
h_projection = np.array([ x/rows for x in img.sum(axis=0)])
threshold = (np.max(h_projection) - np.min(h_projection)) / 4
print("we will use threshold {} for horizontal".format(threshold))
# select the black areas
black_areas = np.where(h_projection < threshold)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
fig.add_subplot(121)
for j in black_areas:
    img[:, j] = 0
    plt.plot((j, j), (0, 1), 'g-')
plt.plot(range(cols), h_projection.T)

v_projection = np.array([ x/cols for x in img.sum(axis=1)])
threshold = (np.max(v_projection) - np.min(v_projection)) / 4
print("we will use threshold {} for vertical".format(threshold))
black_areas = np.where(v_projection < threshold)
fig.add_subplot(122)
for j in black_areas:
    img[j, :] = 0
    plt.plot((0,1), (j,j), 'g-')
plt.plot(v_projection, range(rows))
plt.show()

# obscurate areas on the image
plt.figure(figsize=(16,12))
plt.subplot(211)
plt.title("Image with the projection mask")
plt.imshow(img)

# erode the features
import scipy
plt.subplot(212)
plt.title("Image after erosion (suggestion)")
eroded_img = scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion(img,  structure=np.ones((5,5))).astype(img.dtype)
plt.imshow(eroded_img)
plt.show()
```

So now you have the horizontal and vertical projections, that look like this

[image]

And after that you can apply the mask: there are several ways of doing this, in the code is already applied within the for loop, where we set `img[:,j] = 0` for the columns, and `img[j,:] = 0` for the rows. It was easy and I think intuitive, but you can look for other methods.
As a suggestion, I would say you can look into the morphological operator of [erosion](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion.html) that can help to separate the white parts.
So the output would look like this.

[image]

Unfortunately, the upper and lower part still show white regions. You can manually set the rows to white `img[:10,:] = 0, img[100:,:] = 0`, but that probably would not work on all the images you have (if you are trying to train a neural network I assume you have lots of them, so you need to have a code that works on all of them.

So, since now you ask for segmentation also, this opens another topic. Segmentation is a complex task, and it is not as straightforward as a binary mask. I would strongly suggest you read some material on that before you just apply something without understanding. For example [here a guide on image processing with scipy](https://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/index.html), but you may look for more.
As a suggestion and a small snippet to make it work, you can use the labeling from `scipy.ndimage`.
Here a small part of code (from the [guide](https://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/index.html))

```
label_im, nb_labels = scipy.ndimage.label(eroded_img)
plt.figure(figsize=(16,12))
plt.subplot(211)
plt.title("Segmentation")
plt.imshow(label_im)   
plt.subplot(212)
plt.title("One Object as an example")
plt.imshow(label_im == 6)   # change number for the others!
```

Which will output:

[image]

As an example I showed the `S` letter. if you change `label_im == 6` you will get the next letter. As you will see yourself, it is not always correct and other little pieces of the image are also considered as *objects*. So you will have to work a little bit more on that.

Comment: Thanks, now I have to apply this to the license plate image, should I use mask for that?

Comment: this is already applied to the license plate image, I just downloaded the image you posted on the question. It is hosted on imgur [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXWgw.png) Which mask? You want to remove part of the image (like the Chile text below)?

Comment: My goal is to be able to segment characters, without the edges complicating recognition (the white border part), some plates have a little screw that affirms it to the car and when  transform the image to binary, something like this remains: https://prnt.sc/ss7pct (it doesn't always happen but it can happen), in these cases it makes character segmentation difficult. Then it occurred to me to see the idea of histogram, to leave the image clean without border problems to be able to segment the character in a good way

Comment: So by applying histogram projection I could make character segmentation easier and more effective, but now I have to know how to do it (that each horizontal line separates each character, leaving out the white border of the image)

Comment: ok, sorry. I thought you knew how to do that. Have the feeling the question is very wide, maybe try to specify better what you need. I will update the answer.

Comment: Sorry for not being so specific, I was trying to say that for this the first step would be to remove the white edges with this histogram projection technique. The second part would be to segment the characters with this technique.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help, I would have had a hard time doing it. Just one more thing, how could I separate each character from that image?

Comment: in my opinion, you are asking for a tutorial, not a question. I update this, but this is the last time. You can take it, try to do something on your own, fail if it has to be, and post a specific question again. Please.

Comment: Total thanks, sorry I exceeded it, that it was something that had not come out in 1 week. Really thanks, I learned a lot

Comment: don't worry. happy to have helped, hope to see you soon with new specific questions (:

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62190121/how-to-delete-or-clear-contours-from-image I tried to rely on the histogram but failed